# SSRS Report Integration with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have tried implementing SSRS report integration using report viewer but somehow i am not able to do it.
http://abcd1234/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fMyReportFolder%2fCityList

where abcd1234 is report server and CityList is report name.Above URL is report URL which open report on server.

I am not sure if there is some problem with this URL and we have to change some setting on SSRS server to get some other URL for the report.
i tried using :: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-display-ssrs-report-in-asp-net-mvc-web-application/ 
But not able to do it.
It will be really help,if i can get code same to render report using report viewer having above mentioned URL.

What I have tried:

```
String reportFolder = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSRSReportsFolder"].ToString();


 rvSiteMapping.Height = Unit.Pixel(Convert.ToInt32(Request["Height"])
- 58);
 rvSiteMapping.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;


 rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://abcd1234/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fMyReportFolder"); // Add the Reporting Server URL 
 rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.ReportPath = String.Format("/{0}/{1}", reportFolder, Request["ReportName"].ToString());


 rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: why not use URL directly?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @TonyDong what do you mean by using URL directly? I need to pass some parameter as well from my .net application.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood .. 
i have used rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://abcd1234/") and getting following error : 
"The attempt to connect to the report server failed. Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version.
 The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found."
I am not sure if i am using the correct values server.

Comment: You can pass parameters in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

actually the problem was to give correct server Uri.i was using some wrong URI.When i log in the SSRS server and check server properties then i came to know correct server uri.
for my case it was https://abced1234/reportserver